# WebApp / Servers / Services statistics report

Tags: web-applications, report, monitoring, lamp

Can someone please advice any tool like AwStats to gather reports about my LAMP stack and my WebApp please ?
Something that can help to gather statistics about uptime / services / aplication..etc

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/products/pricing.html) for any log aggregation. You can set up things like triggered alerts, behavioral and big data analysis on events.

If you can keep the amount of data being indexed you can keep the costs quite low.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for an opensource solution and that can be hosted in my servers. :)